# Map/reduce mongodb using two attributes

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I'm practicing with mongo using the sample db restaurants.
The db has the following structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6035397d0076410d79b29bde"),
    "address" : {
        "building" : "522",
        "coord" : [
            -73.95171,
            40.767461
        ],
        "street" : "East   74 Street",
        "zipcode" : "10021"
    },
    "borough" : "Manhattan",
    "cuisine" : "American ",
    "grades" : [
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2014-09-02T00:00:00Z"),
            "grade" : "A",
            "score" : 12
        },
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2013-12-19T00:00:00Z"),
            "grade" : "B",
            "score" : 16
        },
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2013-05-28T00:00:00Z"),
            "grade" : "A",
            "score" : 9
        },
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2012-12-07T00:00:00Z"),
            "grade" : "A",
            "score" : 13
        },
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2012-03-29T00:00:00Z"),
            "grade" : "A",
            "score" : 11
        }
    ],
    "name" : "Glorious Food",
    "restaurant_id" : "40361521"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6035397d0076410d79b29bdf"),
    "address" : {
        "building" : "284",
        "coord" : [
            -73.9829239,
            40.6580753
        ],
        "street" : "Prospect Park West",
        "zipcode" : "11215"
    },
    "borough" : "Brooklyn",
    "cuisine" : "American ",
    "grades" : [
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2014-11-19T00:00:00Z"),
            "grade" : "A",
            "score" : 11
        },
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2013-11-14T00:00:00Z"),
            "grade" : "A",
            "score" : 2
        },
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2012-12-05T00:00:00Z"),
            "grade" : "A",
            "score" : 13
        },
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2012-05-17T00:00:00Z"),
            "grade" : "A",
            "score" : 11
        }
    ],
    "name" : "The Movable Feast",
    "restaurant_id" : "40361606"
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to get the total of cuisines per borought. So, if a borought has 5 resturants, but in this restaurants, 2 serve the same kind of food, my total should be 4.

I'm suposed to use map/reduce/finalize functions, but I can't figure out how.

All exemples I saw, in the map you have just one attribute to filter de data, but I need to group the restaurants of the same borough and then group e count by cuisine.

Can anyone help me? I've been tryng for a long time, didn't get enyware. The best I manage was to count the total of restaurants per borough.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
db.restaurants.aggregate([
    // First group by "borough" and "cousine".
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                "borough": "$borough",
                "cuisine": "$cuisine"
            },
            count: { $first: 1 }
        }
    },
    // Second group by only "borough".
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.borough",
            count: { $sum: "$count" }
        }
    }
]);
```

Output:

```js
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "Brooklyn",
    "count" : 1
},

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "Manhattan",
    "count" : 2
}
```

My test data:

```js
/* 1 createdAt:2/24/2021, 11:35:10 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6036955624f3423874ac9540"),
    "borough" : "Manhattan",
    "cuisine" : "Indian",
    "restaurant_id" : "40361605"
},

/* 2 createdAt:2/24/2021, 11:35:10 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6036955624f3423874ac953f"),
    "borough" : "Brooklyn",
    "cuisine" : "American",
    "restaurant_id" : "40361606"
},

/* 3 createdAt:2/24/2021, 11:35:10 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6036955624f3423874ac953e"),
    "borough" : "Manhattan",
    "cuisine" : "American",
    "restaurant_id" : "40361522"
},

/* 4 createdAt:2/24/2021, 11:35:10 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6036955624f3423874ac953d"),
    "borough" : "Manhattan",
    "cuisine" : "American",
    "restaurant_id" : "40361521"
}
```

Comment: Thanks....it works, but the exercise says to use mapreduce, and I can't figure it out